# I can load the page only once?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I have the classic method `OnNavigatedTo()`:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    // My code
}
```

I wanted to know if the method parameter `NavigationEventArgs`, I could understand if it is new or not new navigation? My app when you start in the `MainPage`, loads the contents of the method `OnNavigatedTo()`, then you open a new page, but pressing the Back button on your phone, you can return to the `MainPage`. If you press the Back button, I would not it loaded again the code within the method `OnNavigatedTo()`.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes put a Boolean state property on the VM of the page to indicate whether the page has been loaded and check/set accordingly. We had to do similar due to the back button on a WP project I worked on.